# How to change cursor during menu item action for a Java Application

Tags: java, macos, swing

I have a java application with UI consisting of JFrame, JTabbedPane and JList (plus other controls). When populating the JList I want to change the cursor to the BUSY cursor. If I invoke the logic to populate the JList from within the JFrame container (e.g. from a button or popup menu action) it works as expected. However, if I invoke the refresh operation from a menu item in the application's jMenuBar menu, the cursor doesn't change, i.e. after clicking on the menu item if I move the mouse cursor over the ui the cursor is not changed while the refresh is occurring.

The code to change the cursor (located in the refresh method) is:

frame1.setCursor(Cursor.getPredefinedCursor(Cursor.WAIT_CURSOR);
. . . refresh logic
frame1.setCursor(Cursor.getDefaultCursor())

I am running the application on Mac OS X 10.9 platform; it is built using Netbeans IDE(V7.4) using java jdk 1.7

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Ok; so the problem apparently has to do with configuring the JMenuBar as a Mac Application menu bar rather than just using it as a java menu bar. If I remove the laf.useScreenMenuBar runtime setting then it works as expected as the menu bar is now part of the JFrame.